# Salesforce Console App slow on Leads

Tags: list-view, console

When I navigate through our salesforce console app and choose "Leads" it takes quite a while to populate the list of open leads. Is there a way to speed up this process? Maybe indexing some of the lead fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List views are primarily affected by the number of rows returned. If you're dealing with a view that has 2,000+ leads, that's probably your problem. Try altering your filters to return fewer than 2,000 records for optimal performance. If you need "all" the open leads, that's a task best left for reporting.